# Failed to delete domain from database

Tags: postgresql, arcgis-10.1, arccatalog, domains, erase

I am trying to delete a domain I am using from ArcCatalog -> Feature Class Properties-> Subtypes-> Domains. But when I try to do that I get this error message:

> Failed to delete a domain from the database.
>
> The domain is used by an attribute rule.

I've checked if there are any locks and there aren't.

Does anyone know  why I can't delete it?

[image]

I use ArcGIS 10.1. Standard on an ArcSDE PostgreSQL Geodatabase.

I was able to delete the field corresponding to the domain, but I still cannot delete the domain. Same error. Plus, when I want to disable the existing subtype I get this message

> Failed to change the subtype field. LInestring or poly boundary is
> self-intersecting

I assume it's just one single problem that messed up the subtype and the domains and I get different error messages.

Comment: The text and graphic show two different errors - perhaps you can make this Question relate only to the error shown in the graphic, and if the other error remains an issue then create a new Question for it.

Comment: You could just disassociate the domain with the field and leave it in the geodatabase.  I don't think it would harm anything to have an unused domain.  Although if your domain is associated with a field, that's likely why you can't delete it in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

There is a Technical Article [Error: Failed to delete a domain from the database](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/29471) that may supply you with an answer.

It says:

> **Cause**
> These errors occur if the domain is applied to one or more fields in the geodatabase.
>
> **Solution or Workaround**
> To delete a domain, it must not be associated with any fields in the geodatabase.

Comment: saw that article. didn't work for me :(

Comment: when trying to associate the domain in question to a field in the geodatabase, I get this error again " Failed to change the default subtype code. Linestring or poly boundary is self-intersecting"

Comment: Linestring or poly boundary is self-intersecting sounds like more of a topology error than a domain error.

Comment: It also sounds like a new Question to me and to fit with the Q&A format of SE GIS should have one submitted rather than confusing its symptoms and causes with the original problem.

Comment: I have no topology in that geodatabase.